# Breadth-first search with ack or grep

Tags: search, grep, ack

When I search e.g. my home directory with `ack` (or `grep`), I normally want to know where I set a specific option.

Since most config files are really close to `~` it would considerably speed up `ack` if I could search breadth-first. Is this possible?

Comment: Sadly the answer seems to be no.

Comment: It seems every couple of months I google this and get back to this page.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet My „solution“ has been to switch to `ag`, which is about 5–10 times faster than `ack` and provides no drawbacks. Combined with switching to SSD I haven’t had the problem since.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know `ack` but with tools such as `grep` I typically use:

```
( find . -maxdepth 1 -print ; find . -mindepth 2 -print ) | xargs -n 50 -exec grep TXT
```

The part between `(` and `)` ensures that first the files at level 1 are listed and after that those at 2 and deeper (you can vary). `xargs` feeds the file names per 50 to `grep`.

Of course it depends on which variant of `find` is available on your platform. If running something from 30 years ago, you will need to use something like sorting on the number of forward slashes.

Comment: MMV (Archlinux): `grep: ./.macromedia/Flash_Player/#SharedObjects/Q2GSRK6Y/www.mixcloud.com/media: Is a directory`

Comment: If you're not going to use `-print0` to find, at least do `find . -maxdepth 1 -exec grep {} +;`. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020